# A particule on a surface

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, gradient-flows

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ define by
$$f(x,y):= x^4 - 6x^2y^2+y^4-2x^2+2y^2.$$

Suppose a particule moves on the surface $z=f(x,y)$ as it progresses always in the same direction where $f$ decrease the faster.

1. If at the time $t=0$ the position of the particule is $(x,y,z)=(2,1,f(2,1))$, in which direction will it be initialy?
2. Show that in general the particule will follow a path along which
   $$xy(x^2-y^2-1)= \alpha.$$

   Where $\alpha$ is a constant.

---

In (1), I suppose I have to calculate the gradient and evaluate it a the initial position of the particule,

$$ \nabla{f}:= (4x^3-12xy^2-4x,-12x^2y+4y^3+4y)$$

Then,

$$\nabla{f}(2,1)=(4,-40) = (1,-10)$$

How can I do the (2)?

Comment: I guess to find the path of the particle $(x(t), y(t))$, you need to solve the system of differential equations:
$x'(t) = 4x(t)^3 - 12x(t)y(t)^2 - 4x(t)$ and 
$y'(t) = -12x(t)^2y(t) + 4y(t)^3 + 4y(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's express this curve in this way

$$y=y(x)$$

If we write this curve in a parametric way, the problem will be so complicated. Instead, I avoid using parameter $t$.

$$(x'(t),y'(t))=-\vec\nabla f(x,y)$$

so

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

To remove $t$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}={~~~\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} ~~~\over ~~~\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}~~~}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-12x^2y+4y^3+4y}{4x^3-12xy^2-4x}=\frac{-4x^2y+y^3+y}{x^3-3xy^2-x}$$

expansion and re-arranging:

$$(-3x^2y+y^3+y)=y'(x^3-3xy^2-x)$$

$$(-3x^2y-y' x^3)+(y^3+3xy^2y')+(y+y'x)=$$
$$(-y x^3)'+(y^3x)'+(yx)'=0$$
$$(-y x^3+y^3x+yx)'=0$$

$$-y x^3+y^3x+yx =C$$
$$xy(- x^2+y^2+1) =C$$

$$xy(x^2-y^2-1) =-C$$